# com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE is deprecated for all apps Android N?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-camera, receiver

I have used com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE & android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE to check whether an image is captured or not in my app.

But it's getting warning **com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE is deprecated for all apps starting with the Android N release to target SDK**

How can I resolve it? Can any one help me for Android N.

My code is

```
 **<receiver android:name=".receiver.CameraReceiver"
           android:enabled="true">
 <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
 <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
 <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>**
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have to rewrite your code as in this anwer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46375945/433718

Answer (score 2):

The [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE) states that it's deprecated in Android N. Relevant part of the docs:

*In Android N this broadcast was removed, and applications are recommended to use JobInfo.Builder.addTriggerContentUri(JobInfo.TriggerContentUri) instead.*

*In Android O this broadcast has been brought back, but only for registered receivers. Apps that are actively running can again listen to the broadcast if they want an immediate clear signal about a picture being taken, however anything doing heavy work (or needing to be launched) as a result of this should still use JobScheduler.*

Comment: I have also use this code JobInfo.Builder.addTriggerContentUri(JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)

but background service not working after app kill in Android N. So have any idea about. Please tell me.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html#media-broadcasts) in the section called "Restrictions on NEW_PICTURE and NEW_VIDEO"

Comment: The example shows how to observe newly added photos to MediaStore. It's different from detecting newly taken photos as MediaStore notifies about newly created pictures with other software, or just copied.

Comment: Can somebody clarify what's a "registered" reveiver? What's the opposite?