# How to get broadcast of new media in gallery?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get notified of a new picture or video added to the phone gallery. I would need to obtain the new media's URI. The purpose is so i can automatically back it up. So i need a register that is set in the background to continuously listen or check for new media added to the gallery, and captures the Uri. This used to be done with a broadcast receiver such as:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.CameraEventReceiver"
    android:label="CameraEventReceiver">
    <intent-filter>

        <!-- <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" /> -->
        <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />

        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

However this was deprecated in API level 24. I target API 21-26. Can someone show me how to do this with JobSchedulers like android docs say too?

Comment: Below API 24 you can still register your receiver in the manifest. Starting API 24 you have an example here from the official doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html?#addTriggerContentUri%28android.app.job.JobInfo.TriggerContentUri%29

Comment: @Gauthier that monitors for changes. Not exclusively for new photos. If you would like the bounty, and since you seem to understand the situation. Modify the example code to search for new photos for an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **In API level 23 above Job scheduling is been introduce to perform the task**
>
> So I am placing sample of Job Scheduling which can help you

**JobSchedulerService.java**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class JobSchedulerService extends JobService {

    private Context mContext;
    private static final int ASJOBSERVICE_JOB_ID = 999;

    // A pre-built JobInfo we use for scheduling our job.
    private static JobInfo JOB_INFO = null;

    public static int a(Context context) {
        int schedule = ((JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class)).schedule(JOB_INFO);
        Log.i("PhotosContentJob", "JOB SCHEDULED!");
        return schedule;
    }

    // Schedule this job, replace any existing one.
    public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        if (JOB_INFO != null) {
            a(context);
        } else {
            JobScheduler js = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
            JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(ASJOBSERVICE_JOB_ID,
                    new ComponentName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, JobSchedulerService.class.getName()));
            builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 1));
            builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 1));
            builder.setTriggerContentMaxDelay(500);
            JOB_INFO = builder.build();
            js.schedule(JOB_INFO);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
        mContext = this;
        // Did we trigger due to a content change?
        if (params.getTriggeredContentAuthorities() != null) {
            if (params.getTriggeredContentUris() != null) {
                // If we have details about which URIs changed, then iterate through them
                // and collect either the ids that were impacted or note that a generic
                // change has happened.
                ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Uri uri : params.getTriggeredContentUris()) {
                    if (uri != null) {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //Perform your task here
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                jobFinished(params, true); // see this, we are saying we just finished the job
                // We will emulate taking some time to do this work, so we can see batching happen.
                scheduleJob(this);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

In Manifest File

```
<service
    android:name=".services.JobSchedulerService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

In Your MainActivity.java which ever your launcher file

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                JobSchedulerService.scheduleJob(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: triggering it in mainactivity means it will only detect it when the user opens the app. I need it to run in the background. Can you add that part? then  i can mark as accepted answer

Comment: When User will Open the application the job scheduling will register and after that the when the **onStartJob(JobParameters)** method will call in that I have add code ***scheduleJob(this);*** this will create the jobinfo object again and will schedule the job only one time application need to be open for the first time to start the job.

Comment: What about below API 23

Comment: For below version u need to use the broad cast receiver

Comment: Thanks @AmjadKhan.  Its work amazing if just 1 photo comes to DCIM, let say I have copied 10 photos together, i need to know exactly all the 10 photos. Can you guide me, how to modify it

Comment: @Muhammad Hashim Shafiq if you are getting the single photo like that if you have 10 photo it will all come one by one in sequence you will receive the onStartJob method call, after that you have to scheduleJob then you will get the next image at last of onStartJob.

Comment: I can confirm, this code is working. I'd incoperate `a()`s code into  `scheduleJob(Context context)` and remove `a()` for a better code style.